# Django Custom Backend Documentation Discrepancy

Tags: python, django

I am having difficulty understanding how Django's documentation has outlined the overriding of the authenticate method in contrib.auth.models.Users.  According to the code below from [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/customizing/#writing-an-authentication-backend), wouldnt the authenticate method succeed if the method was passed a valid username and a valid hash that exists anywhere in the database regardless of whether it matches the password for the supplied primary key field (username, email, etc...) or not.  Is there something that check_password is doing that I am not seeing like ensuring that the field that was passed alongside of the password is checked behind the scenes?  Because this supplied example appears to have a flaw.

```
# From Django 1.10 Documentation
def authenticate(self, username=None, password=None):
    login_valid = (settings.ADMIN_LOGIN == username)
    pwd_valid = check_password(password, settings.ADMIN_PASSWORD)
    if login_valid and pwd_valid:
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(username=username)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            # Create a new user. There's no need to set a password
            # because only the password from settings.py is checked.
            user = User(username=username)
            user.is_staff = True
            user.is_superuser = True
            user.save()
        return user
    return None
```

Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand your concern. As it says in the comment, this isn't using a password from the database at all since it's just designed to match the one in settings. It might be clearer if you describe an "attack" on this backend that would allow an unauthorized user to be authenticated.

Comment: right its not a password from the database I saw that, however, suppose you have 2 users in the database user1, user2. password for user1 is password1 while the password for user2 is password2.  Assume that I pass user: user1 and password: password2 to the authenticate function. As this code reads, this would authenticate me as a user1 even though i gave user2's password

Comment: There are no passwords in the database - at least as far as this backend is concerned. If some other backend decides to populate that field it's irrelevant to this one. All this does is look for a match with the password specified in the settings. If you decide to put user1's username and user2's password in the settings file, then you will get the result you asked for.

Comment: Maybe I should have said, assume that you were going to use authenticate in a form and instead of using a user defined in settings, I am going to use data obtained within request.POST['username'] and ['password'].  I apologize for not being clear what I was stating.  This is the documentation that django provides for a custom backend and my question was if someone puts this into a form with the same login_valid and pwd_valid logic, would it be susceptible to accepting form data with a valid username and password regardless of if the password is associated with the username that was passed.

Comment: As I read further through the documentation, django-project does offer https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/backends.py, which, gives a true implementation of this.  I dont know why they dont use this code in the example on the custom auth backend docs page because this is a more realistic implementation of a custom backend.

Comment: Yes, I think your confusion is because you're reading way too much into this example. It's just an example of what it means to write the code for a custom authentication backend. It is in no way suggesting specific authentication logic that you might want to use, and is not meant to be realistic. It is unrealistic because only an unrealistically simple backend will be short enough to fit as a example in documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[authenticate()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.authenticate) function returns user for which you attach session using [login()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/default/#how-to-log-a-user-in)

> Use authenticate() to verify a set of credentials. It takes
>   credentials as keyword arguments, username and password for the
>   default case, checks them against each authentication backend, and
>   returns a User object if the credentials are valid for a backend. If
>   the credentials aren’t valid for any backend or if a backend raises
>   PermissionDenied, it returns None.:

In case of the following authentication backend username and password are passed to it.

- Password is compared with one set in Django settings and user object
  is queried from database.
- If user with that username does not exist   backend creates new user.

This backend works even though from security aspect it is not best  one :)